# Using async.series in node.js

Tags: node.js, async.js

I am new to Node.js. One of the things I like about Node.js is its async nature. However, at this moment, I have a need for a synchronous operation. For
that reason, I've been looking at the async module. However, I still can't figure out what I'm trying to do.

I'm trying to execute 2 static operations, and a variable number of other operations sequentially. After all of those are complete, I then want to do something. In other words, in psedo code, I'm trying to do:

```
var total = getValue();

executeOperation1();
executeOperation2(); 
for (var i=0; i<total; i++) {
    executeOperationX(i);
}
doCompletionOperation();
```

Each of my main operations (executeOperation1(), executeOperation2(), and executeOperationX(...)) runs asynchronously. From my understanding, I need to use
async.series. However, I'm not sure what this looks like syntactically. Can someone show me how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you need some callbacks to work with asynchronous functions.
async.series looks like this:

```
getValue(function(value){
    var total = value;
    async.series([
        function(callback){
            executeOperation1(function(){
                callback();
            });
        },function(callback){
            executeOperation2(function(){
                callback();
            });
        },function(callback){
               for(var i=0;i<total;i++){        
                 executeOperationX(i);
               }
        }],function(){
              doCompletionOperation();
        });
   });
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, I don't understand where the 'callback' parameter that is passed into the function comes from. Can you please explain that to me?

Comment: `async` passes it to you. When you invoke `async.series`, it understands that you're going to supply it a list of functions that each expect a callback as a parameter.  It passes you that callback, because that is how you let it know your function is done and that it can proceed to the next one.  If you pass an error to the supplied callback, it will skip any later functions in the array and proceed directly to the very last function A-0- listed, which is where you can handle any errors that arose.